# moving the csv download link in ActiveAdmin to the sidebar and maintain its default behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activeadmin

How do it move the csv download link from the bottom to the sidebar and still keep its behavior? i.e. if the page is paginated it downloads the paginated results or if I filter out the results in the index it downloads those results. If I do this it returns all the users instead the scoped results after a filter.

```
#app/admin/user.rb

sidebar :download_links do 
 ul do 
  li link_to 'download CSV',admin_users_path(:format => :csv)
  li link_to 'render JSON',admin_users_path(:format => :json)
  li link_to 'render XML',admin_users_path(:format => :xml) 
 end 
end

#the index action    
permit_params :first_name, :last_name
index do
 selectable_column
  id_column    
  column :first_name
  column :last_name
  ..........#other fields   
  actions
end

#the csv genarator
   csv do
    column :first_name
    column :last_name
    .........# other fields
   end
```

Comment: can you post the controller code

Comment: @MZaragoza  i have posted what is in the user resource . The csv in also a function of AA . I've not put the `AciveAdmin.register User` as it will not be necessary.